# Get user roles written in one line wrapped in HTML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to get each user's roles written in one line, wrapped into some HTML.
There are three tables:

```
BAUSER - users
BAUSGR - which roles user has
BAGROP - roles
```

Desired output looks like:

```
+----------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| USER_KEY |   USER_NAME    |                                          ROLES                                           |
+----------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        1 | MIKE BAILEY    | <div>TESTING ROLE</div><div>ANOTHER ROLE</div><div>FOURTH ONE</div><div>SIXTH TEST</div> |
|        2 | GEORGE SMITH   | <div>TESTING ROLE</div><div>ANOTHER ROLE</div><div>FOURTH ONE</div><div>SIXTH TEST</div> |
|        3 | JIMMY BUSH     | <div>TESTING ROLE</div><div>ANOTHER ROLE</div><div>FOURTH ONE</div><div>SIXTH TEST</div> |
|        4 | SERGEY CLINTON | <div>TESTING ROLE</div><div>ANOTHER ROLE</div><div>FOURTH ONE</div><div>SIXTH TEST</div> |
+----------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I've already tried is use `FOR XML PATH`, but it's not giving me desired results:

```
SELECT U.USER_KEY, U.USER_FNM + ' ' + U.USER_LNM [USER_NAME], (SELECT '<div>' + OP.GROP_NME + '</div>' FROM BAGROP OP_1 WHERE OP_1.GROP_KEY = OP.GROP_KEY FOR XML PATH(''))
FROM BAUSER U JOIN BAUSGR GR ON U.USER_KEY = GR.USER_KEY
JOIN BAGROP OP ON GR.GROP_KEY = OP.GROP_KEY
```

My main problem how group user keys and user names and add column with user roles.

Table creation and inserts:

```
CREATE TABLE BAUSER
(
USER_KEY INT,
USER_FNM VARCHAR(50),
USER_LNM VARCHAR(50)
)


CREATE TABLE BAUSGR
(
USER_KEY INT,
GROP_KEY INT
)

CREATE TABLE BAGROP
(
GROP_KEY INT,
GROP_NME VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO BAGROP(GROP_KEY,GROP_NME)
VALUES(1,'FIRST ROLE')
GO
INSERT INTO BAGROP(GROP_KEY,GROP_NME)
VALUES(2,'TESTING ROLE')
GO
INSERT INTO BAGROP(GROP_KEY,GROP_NME)
VALUES(3,'ANOTHER ROLE')
GO
INSERT INTO BAGROP(GROP_KEY,GROP_NME)
VALUES(4,'FOURTH ONE')
GO
INSERT INTO BAGROP(GROP_KEY,GROP_NME)
VALUES(5,'SIXTH TEST')
GO
INSERT INTO BAGROP(GROP_KEY,GROP_NME)
VALUES(6,'SEVEN - ROLE 7')
GO

INSERT INTO BAUSER(USER_KEY,USER_FNM,USER_LNM)
VALUES(1,'MIKE','BAILEY')
GO
INSERT INTO BAUSER(USER_KEY,USER_FNM,USER_LNM)
VALUES(2,'GEORGE','SMITH')
GO
INSERT INTO BAUSER(USER_KEY,USER_FNM,USER_LNM)
VALUES(3,'JIMMY','BUSH')
GO
INSERT INTO BAUSER(USER_KEY,USER_FNM,USER_LNM)
VALUES(4,'SERGEY','CLINTON')
GO
INSERT INTO BAUSER(USER_KEY,USER_FNM,USER_LNM)
VALUES(5,'DONALD','TESTING')
GO


INSERT INTO BAUSGR(USER_KEY,GROP_KEY)
VALUES(1,2)
GO
INSERT INTO BAUSGR(USER_KEY,GROP_KEY)
VALUES(1,3)
GO
INSERT INTO BAUSGR(USER_KEY,GROP_KEY)
VALUES(1,4)
GO
INSERT INTO BAUSGR(USER_KEY,GROP_KEY)
VALUES(1,5)
GO
INSERT INTO BAUSGR(USER_KEY,GROP_KEY)
VALUES(2,1)
GO
INSERT INTO BAUSGR(USER_KEY,GROP_KEY)
VALUES(2,2)
GO
INSERT INTO BAUSGR(USER_KEY,GROP_KEY)
VALUES(2,3)
GO
INSERT INTO BAUSGR(USER_KEY,GROP_KEY)
VALUES(2,4)
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT U.USER_KEY, U.USER_FNM + ' ' + U.USER_LNM [USER_NAME]
, ROLES= (SELECT  GROP_NME AS div 
         FROM BAUSER U1 
         JOIN BAUSGR GR1 ON U1.USER_KEY = GR1.USER_KEY
         JOIN BAGROP OP1 ON GR1.GROP_KEY = OP1.GROP_KEY         
         WHERE U.USER_KEY = U1.USER_KEY ORDER BY GROP_NME FOR XML PATH('')) 
FROM BAUSER U 
JOIN BAUSGR GR ON U.USER_KEY = GR.USER_KEY
--JOIN BAGROP OP ON GR.GROP_KEY = OP.GROP_KEY
GROUP BY U.USER_KEY, U.USER_FNM + ' ' + U.USER_LNM;
```

**Edited version (simplified, removing FROM BAUSER in inner query):**

```
SELECT U.USER_KEY, U.USER_FNM + ' ' + U.USER_LNM [USER_NAME]
, ROLES= (SELECT   GROP_NME AS div   
         FROM  BAUSGR GR1  
         JOIN BAGROP OP1 ON GR1.GROP_KEY = OP1.GROP_KEY         
         WHERE U.USER_KEY = GR1.USER_KEY
          ORDER BY GROP_NME
          FOR XML PATH('') 
         ) 
FROM BAUSER U 
JOIN BAUSGR GR ON U.USER_KEY = GR.USER_KEY    
GROUP BY U.USER_KEY, U.USER_FNM + ' ' + U.USER_LNM;
```

Output (is the same for both queries):

```
+----+----------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    | USER_KEY |  USER_NAME   |                                          ROLES                                           |
+----+----------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |        1 | MIKE BAILEY  | <div>ANOTHER ROLE</div><div>FOURTH ONE</div><div>SIXTH TEST</div><div>TESTING ROLE</div> |
|  2 |        2 | GEORGE SMITH | <div>ANOTHER ROLE</div><div>FIRST ROLE</div><div>FOURTH ONE</div><div>TESTING ROLE</div> |
+----+----------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: @FrenkyB : added another version (just removed FROM BAUSGR in inner query)

Comment: Works like a charm :) Why ORDER BY in inner query?

Comment: Just  to have the roles in same positions (where they are the same).  You can omit it if you want

Comment: I understand now. Yes, it's better to have ORDER BY. Thanks a lot for help :)